# How to count the numbers of excels in Excel, based on a criteria from another column

Tags: excel, function, count

I have an excel spreadsheet that contains a "Customer ID" field and a "Check ID" field. I need to count the number of check id's associated with that customer id for a specific date?

```
## Customer ID ##  ## Check ID##  ## Check Date##

   2554               823488         04/24/2015
   2554               823489         04/24/2015
   4856               823450         04/24/2015
```

So Customer 2554 would have a count of 2 and Customer 4856 would have a count of 1.

Comment: So sorry it would be the date of the check.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are A, B and C (`4856` in A4) try in E2 and copied down to suit:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,C2)
```

and replace `C2` with the cell absolute reference to your "specific date".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Excel 2010 or later you should be able to use the `=COUNTIFS()` function.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `SUMPRODUCT`function (Excel 2003 and +) that will allow you to do such a thing !

It make the product of two arrays and then return the sum of them.
So if you construct an array that give 1 if a criteria is satisfied and 0 otherwise, you will have the sum of cells that satisfy the criteria.

Example : `=SUMPRODUCT( (A:A=2554)*1 )` will return 2.

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616